# Percent word problem - calculate store cost

Tags: percentages

Here's a word problem having to do with percentages, and the answer doesn't make sense. A furniture store is selling a desk for `$300`. If the store makes a `25%` profit on the sale, what is the store's cost for the desk? The answer is `$240` but how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say that $x$ is the cost for the store. The store makes a profit of $25$% which means that the selling price is $1.25 x$; so $1.25 x=300$ then $x=300/1.25=240$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the cost of the desk for the store is 100%. We know 25% more than that is \$300. Hence, 125% of the cost price of the desk is \$300, and the original price is therefore $100\times \frac{\$300}{125}$. Since $\$300/125$ = 1% of cost price, and then we just multiply by 100 to find the original 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula:

> $$\frac{\text{percent of change}}{100} = \frac{\text{change in price}}{\text{original price}}$$

Let $x$ = the **original** price.

Then

$$\frac{1}{4} = \frac{300-x}{x}$$

$x = $ $240.

Comment: Thanks, skullpatrol. BTW, how do you enter the equations on this site?

Answer (score 1):

If the store makes a $25$% on $300.

So, $300 is 125% of store's cost. Let the store's cost is x dollars.

Now, make the proportion,
$$\dfrac{300}{x}=\dfrac{125}{100}$$
$$125x=30000$$
$$x=\dfrac{30000}{125}$$
$$x=240$$
So, the store's cost is $240.